# SUM on a single column based on different tables on SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have two tables, min_attribution and max_attribution which looks like this

```
session_id    attribution
1               search
2                 home

session_id    attribution
1               search
2                other
```

And here is the MRS

```
CREATE TABLE min_attribution
(session_id   INT, 
 attribution VARCHAR(20)
)

CREATE TABLE max_attribution
(session_id   INT, 
 attribution VARCHAR(20)
)

Insert into min_attribution values (1,'search')
Insert into min_attribution values (2,'home')
Insert into max_attribution values (1,'search')
Insert into max_attribution values (2,'other')
```

I am trying to write a query where, depending on the value of attribution, a score is given and added for each user ID. For example, if in the first table the value for attribution is search, add 40 and do the same with the other table, but adding 30. Expected output:

```
    session_id  search  home    other
         1        70     0        0
         2         0    40        30
```

What I did was trying to create a column for each of the possible attribution values (there are only a few) and add the results from each table, starting with "search", but it is not adding properly. This is my query

```
SELECT min_attribution.session_id, SUM(
        (CASE WHEN min_attribution.attribution = "search" THEN 40  ELSE 0 END) + 
        (CASE WHEN max_attribution.attribution = "search" THEN 30  ELSE 0 END)) search
FROM min_attribution,
     max_attribution
GROUP BY min_attribution.session_id
```

And the resulting table (current output, only for the search column):

```
session_id  search
1            110
2             30
```

Any ideas? ( I am using BigQuery)

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed!

Comment: SInce you have no join condition, you get a cartesian product.

Comment: you should update your question with more details - also see [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant thank you. updated.

Comment: @linacarrillo - Can you please clarify how/why you `110` and `30` to be in expected the output - based on described logic - I have hard time getting it :o(

Answer (score 1):

I think you want `union all`:

```
select session_id,
       40 * countif(attribute = 'search'),
       40 * countif(attribute = 'home'),
       40 * countif(attribute = 'other')
from ((select session_id, attribution
       from min_attribution
      ) union all
      (select session_id, attribution
       from max_attribution
      )
     ) s
group by session_id;
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply!! Now, what if I had to add a different value depending on the table ? for example 20 if it is the attribute in min_attribution and 40 in max_attribution

Comment: This worked perfectly by the way, but now I need to consider also a case when I give these different points based on the different tables

Comment: @linacarrillo . . . You can do the multiplication in the subqueries.